# Fetching data from Facebook multiple times in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am new to iPhone programming using below code i am login in Facebook and fetching data from Facebook like email id,username after that emailid i am sending to server.But my problem is if already login in Facebook means automatically its calling 
  - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                                    user:(id)user in this method email id sending to server.I don't want like this if i click on button then only i want to fetch Facebook email id and send to server.Please can any one give some idea how to solve it.

```
-(void)viewdidload
        {  
        FBLoginView *fbLoginview =
            [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"email",nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends];

            fbLoginview.frame = CGRectMake(30, 10, 200, 30);
            for (id obj in fbLoginview.subviews)
            {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                {
                    loginWithFbButton =  obj;
                    loginWithFbButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
                    [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:69.0/255.0 green:115.0/255.0 blue:185.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
                    [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                    [loginWithFbButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                    [loginWithFbButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:227.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:0.6].CGColor];
                    loginWithFbButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                    loginWithFbButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
                    [loginWithFbButton setTitle:@"         Get info from Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [loginWithFbButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
                    loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


                    CAGradientLayer *gradient1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
                    gradient1.frame = loginWithFbButton.bounds;

                    UIColor *startColour1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
                    UIColor *endColour1 = [UIColor  colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 green:119.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

                    gradient1.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColour1 CGColor], (id)[endColour1 CGColor], nil];
                    [loginWithFbButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient1 atIndex:0];
                    [fbLoginview addSubview:loginWithFbButton];
                }

                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                {
                    UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
                    loginLabel.text = nil;
                    loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 26);
                }
            }

            fbLoginview.delegate = self;

            [loginTempview3 addSubview:fbLoginview];
        }
```

fetching

```
    - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                                user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

        NSLog(@"Loginvieewww");
       // self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
        //self.profilePic.profileID = @"1772134559592493";
       // NSLog(@"usr_id::%@",user.id); NSLog(@"%@",user);

        NSLog(@"usr_first_name::%@",user.first_name);
        NSString *emailiddd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]];

        NSLog(@"%@",emailiddd);
        NSLog(@"usr_last_nmae::%@",user.last_name);
        NSLog(@"usr_Username::%@",user.username);
        NSLog(@"usr_b_day::%@",user.birthday);

     NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@",emailiddd];

                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
                NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://54.221.218.162/index.php/api/userClass/registerFBUser/format/xml"]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];
                NSLog(@"Aslam here");
                NSLog(@"%@",request);

                NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

                if (theConnection) {
                    webData = [NSMutableData data];
                    NSLog(@"%@",webData);
                }
                else
                {

                }
}
```

Thanks
Aslam